# Getting the values of objects stored inside an array of arrays and sum them Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, iteration

I Have an Array of Objects that contains 4 parameters. `valueMAX valueMIN valueAVERAGE, TIME`.
My problem is that sometimes this array can get huge, and I'm trying to split the array in little ones so I can make an average value. and insert it as a unique value.

for example: my array is 300 objects, and i'm splitting it in 20 arrays inside an another array.
how i can loop the array of arrays so i can get only the `valueMAX` of the objects, sum it and store it?
I'm gonna paste some pieces of my code so i can get things clearer

```
JSONArray resultArray= response.getJSONArray("result");
             Trends trends = new Trends();
```

//adding values to primary array

```
 for(int i=0; i<resultArray.size(); i++) {
                 oggTrend.add(new Trends(trends.getRealDate(response.getJSONArray("result").getJSONObject(i).getIntValue("clock"))
                         , Double.parseDouble(response.getJSONArray("result").getJSONObject(i).getString("value_max"))
                         , Double.parseDouble(response.getJSONArray("result").getJSONObject(i).getString("value_avg"))
                         , Double.parseDouble(response.getJSONArray("result").getJSONObject(i).getString("value_min"))));
             }


             int resultSize = resultArray.size();
```

//method for splicing the primary array

```
static <T> List<List<T>> chopped(List<T> list, final int L) {
    List<List<T>> parts = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
    final int N = list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += L) {
        parts.add(new ArrayList<T>(
            list.subList(i, Math.min(N, i + L)))
        );
    }
    return parts;
}




   if(resultSize>300 && resultSize<400) {

    //splicing the array in an array with lots of arrays that has 12 values
    ObjectSplit=chopped(oggTrend, 12);


//first loop to save the list array that contains the arrays with the objects
for (int i = 0; i < ObjectSplit.size(); i++) {


  List<Trends> list = ObjectSplit.get(i);
  System.out.println("+------list-----+");

//looping the list array that only has objects inside
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {

//getting the average value with getter from object

    System.out.println(list.get(j).getMediaAverage() + "/----------val-------------/");

//trying to sum the average values from the objects inside list
fin += list.get(j).getMediaAverage();

   }

 }
}
```

when i system.out the values are this

```
+------list-----+
15.369/----------val-------------/
15.3316/----------val-------------/
15.3814/----------val-------------/
15.2943/----------val-------------/
15.3316/----------val-------------/
15.3814/----------val-------------/
15.2072/----------val-------------/
15.1325/----------val-------------/
15.3276/----------val-------------/
15.3004/----------val-------------/
15.1829/----------val-------------/
15.3316/----------val-------------/
+------list-----+
15.369/----------val-------------/
15.3316/----------val-------------/
15.3814/----------val-------------/
15.2943/----------val-------------/
15.3316/----------val-------------/
15.3814/----------val-------------/
15.2072/----------val-------------/
15.3316/----------val-------------/
15.369/----------val-------------/
15.3316/----------val-------------/
15.3814/----------val-------------/
15.2819/----------val-------------/
+------list-----+
15.3316/----------val-------------/
15.3814/----------val-------------/
15.2072/----------val-------------/
15.3316/----------val-------------/
15.369/----------val-------------/
15.3316/----------val-------------/
15.3814/----------val-------------/
15.2819/----------val-------------/
15.3316/----------val-------------/
15.3814/----------val-------------/
15.2072/----------val-------------/
15.3316/----------val-------------/
+------list-----+
```

so the values are grouped well, i don't know how to sum these 12 values and add it to an object, after it passes iterating to the next array with the next 12 objects.
sorry for the poor explanation. My English is pretty bad. I wish someone can help

Comment: Can you please share your complete code for better understanding?

Comment: paste.ofcode.org/Ptayg5Rk99ZX6RPxLr6vaL here is the main part. the main too look out is insertdailyvalues().   paste.ofcode.org/3b3ZrayNDR8CmFuRqiCKQ4S .Again sorry for pasting the link to the code like this. and Sorry for the bad code format.

Comment: So to clarify, do you want to sum all the groups into one big value or have a sum for each group? (Should the result be a number or a list of numbers?)

Comment: I'd like to have a sum for each group and eventually adding them to another array as a unique value. I hape that is pretty clear. Sorry for the long response time